# How can I center this submit button?

Tags: html, css, forms, margin, centering

I'm working on [this page](http://ceramicsbysolo.com/product/buttermilk-long-beach-blue-mug/) and trying to center the Add to Cart (submit) button within it's parent div. I've tried various methods but can't get it to move at all.

I've tried `form.cart { margin:auto; text-align:center; }` and `.single_add_to_cart_button {    margin:auto; text-align:center; }`, neither of which do anything.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why won't this css button center inside div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756662/why-wont-this-css-button-center-inside-div)

Comment: You have `float: left` applied to the button. Remove it

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML here, as well.  You will get much better, as well as faster responses.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `float: left` from the `button` with a class of `single_add_to_cart_button`

Comment: Thanks. I removed the `float:left` from that button, but it still won't seem to center... Am I missing something?

Comment: did you update that page? cause I still see the float there. It's on `.button`. If this is needed for other buttons you can add `float: none` on `.single_add_to_cart_button` to override it

Answer (score 1):

try make text align center on parent (form)

```css
form.cart {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.single_add_to_cart_button { float:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

as jmore009 said remove `float:left;` and then add `margin:0 auto 0 auto !important;` to class of `single_add_to_cart_button`